# How to combine 3 flavors in 30 in to 1 product

Tags: magento-1.9

I have 30 flavors of pizza.
Simple products.
I need to register a product that let me combine up to 3 flavors on a pizza only .. hi, split a pizza in 3 flavors ...
How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to sell pizza where customer can choose 3 flavor in product at same time.

for that you can create [custom option](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-product-custom-options.html)

other wise for one product one option you can use above answer and  create configurable product

Comment: ok @Flukats try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Yo can make a configurable product. In the magento user guide you can know how.
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html

For more configurable product (like diferent size and flavours pizza) you can use the bundle product.
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-bundle.html

Comment: Always a pleasure! @Flukats

Comment: Adrià, Look up and see if you can give me an idea

Comment: I still think there is a way to do it with configurable products. I'm looking if there is way to show/hide dropdowns with dependencies.

Comment: I must apologize. I confused the configurable product with the bundle. I leave the link in my original response. Let me know if the answer has been useful.

Comment: I believe the path will be this ... I'm going to burn neurons here to see if I can and then post the answer.  tks..

Comment: Very well, I tried everything and a little more but the problem is in the conditions of size (PMG) and then select the amount of flavors (1,2 or 3).
These conditions can not be programmed in magento unless there is a plugin for this.

Comment: Ok. I try to make it and you're right there is no way to make it dependant. I let you here a link to another cuestion pretty same like yours with a list of modules that can help.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16369/49865

Comment: Thanks man, I think this will solve already I contacted them to know if it's possible the component to do what I need ... thank you from the heart.